# touchpad pointer moves randomly upon release

Tags: 11.10, touchpad

I've just installed 11.10.
I then updated my install.

Now, whenever I move the pointer via the touchpad it jumps around upon release.
It is totally unusable and i'm using a mouse which is fine.

I have a Sony Vaio VPCE82Z0E.

Everything else is working perfectly, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Nearly 7 years later and the issue persists... Dell Latitude 3540 /w Lubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Same thing with an Asus

Answer (score 0):

In dash , search for touchpad, a window opens. Go to touchpad section and try changing acceleration and sensitivity in Pointer speed section - In my case which are default they are zero

Comment: mouse is slower, but still moving after i release